# Select the site where the employee have reported more compare to other sites

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 columns in my table.

```
emp_name | emp_id | site | date_of_work
blhf | 2323 | NAM | Jan-01-2020
blhf | 2323 | NAM | Jan-02-2020
blhf | 2323 | NAM | Jan-03-2020
blhf | 2323 | NAM | Jan-04-2020
blhf2| 2323 | NAM | Jan-01-2020
blhf2 | 2323 | NAM | Jan-02-2020
blhf2| 2323 | ASIA | Jan-03-2020
blhf | 2323 | ASIA | Jan-05-2020
blhf | 2323 | ASIA | Jan-06-2020
blhf | 2323 | ASIA | Jan-07-2020
```

How can I select the site where the employee have a max(date_of_work) or more work day?

Ex. `Output`.

```
blhf | NAM
blhf2 | NAM
```

Thank you

Comment: Learn how to ask question here. https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think I sort of understand what you're looking for. Something along the lines of;

```
Select emp_name, Site, Count(Date_of_work) as Total_Days_worked from TABLE group by 
emp_name, site
```

This will get it done, but if you're in a production environment I would add the emp_id to the select and group by. I don't know how your table is setup, but most companies would use an EMP_ID as the primary key. If we used the above statement and you happened to have 2 employees with the same name, they would get grouped together as a single record. Adding the primary key avoids those situations. I would suggest;

```
Select emp_name, emp_id, Site, Count(Date_of_work) as Total_Days_worked from TABLE 
group by emp_id, emp_name, site
```